# Flex Datagrid select multiple rows and send to amfphp backend

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, amfphp

I was researching over the forums around the internet for some solution to send and ArrayCollection to AmfPHP but I didn't find good responses for that and how I can access the array on PHP side to include into a MySQL table.

My problem:

I have a Flex datagrid populated with some Name and Email and I want create a way to permit  users to create a group and select the Name to be part of this group. I saw in Flash Builder debugger that the data are being send good as ArrayCollection (transformed from Vector to Object also) and the problem still in how can I access this array on PHP side.

Here is ArrayCollection being send to AmfPHP:

```
[0] Object (@cf87311)   
[1] Object (@d4bfcb9)   
[2] Object (@d4d3479)
```

Here is the keys and values of the Array:

```
[0] Object (@cf87311)   
    id  "2" 
    nome    "David" 
    username    "david" 
[1] Object (@d4bfcb9)   
    id  "3" 
    nome    "jose"  
    username    "jose@jose.com" 
[2] Object (@d4d3479)   
    id  "4" 
    nome    "joao"
    username    "joao@joao.com"
```

Does anyone know what I have to do to have access to the field "id" in this array ?

Best Regards !

Rafael Tavares

Answer (score 1):

AMFPHP will translate your actionscript object into a PHP object. Pass the arraycollection as one param. On the PHP side you would use it as:

```
function myfunction( $Object_param )
{
   foreach( $Object_param as $Object )
   {
       echo $Object[ 'id' ];
       echo $Object[ 'nome' ];
   }
}
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your help !

I've tested now and it is not working.

There are no values assigned for $Object['id'] object for each component of the array.

I am transforming vector to object this way:

var temp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
 var selIndices:Vector.<int> = datagrid_grupo_usuarios.selectedIndices;
 var selItems:Vector.<Object> = datagrid_grupo_usuarios.selectedItems;
 var numItems:Number = selIndices.length;
 for (var i:Number = 0; i<numItems; i++){
  temp.addItem(selItems[i]);
 }

Is it right ?

What can I do for get this working ?

Thanks !

Comment: How are you passing the AC to php?

Comment: `protected function button_criar_grupo_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 var temp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
 var selIndices:Vector.<int> = datagrid_grupo_usuarios.selectedIndices;
 var selItems:Vector.<Object> = datagrid_grupo_usuarios.selectedItems;
 var numItems:Number = selIndices.length;
 for (var i:Number = 0; i<numItems; i++){
  temp.addItem(selItems[i]);
 }
 var params:Object = new Object
 params.usuarios=temp;
 criar_grupo.getOperation("retornaCriaGrupo").arguments = params;
 criar_grupo.getOperation("retornaCriaGrupo").send();
}`

Comment: `<s:RemoteObject id="criar_grupo" destination="amfphp" source="Login" showBusyCursor="true">
   <s:method name="retornaCriaGrupo" result="retornaCriaGrupo(event)" fault="onFault(event)">
    <s:arguments>
    <!-- <nome_grupo></nome_grupo> -->
     <usuarios></usuarios>
     <!--<usuario></usuario> -->
    </s:arguments>
   </s:method>
  </s:RemoteObject>`

Comment: PHP function
`public function retornaCriaGrupo($Object_param){
$mysql = mysql_connect(DATABASE_SERVER, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db( DATABASE_NAME );
foreach($Object_param as $Object=>$value){
$query="insert into grupo_usuario (id_grupo,id_usuario) values ('1','".$Object[ 'id' ]."')";
                                $result = mysql_query($query,$mysql);
                }
                if ($result){
                return 1;
                }else{
                return 999;
                }
        }`

Comment: Change PHP to: foreach($Object_param as $Obj ) - object might be a reserved word. Change your query too. Also - put a 'error_log( print_r( $Object_param, true ))' after your function declaration to see if the param is being passed in correctly. This will write to the php log.

Comment: Great! The foreach still not working. I changed your suggestions and the parameters is seems to be passed ok. 
See the php log: `Mon Nov 26 17:54:46 2012] [error] [client 189.121.146.49] stdClass Object\n(\n    [_externalizedData] => Array\n        (\n            [0] => stdClass Object\n                (\n                    [id] => 3\n                    [tipo_usuario] => 0\n                    [username] => jose@jos\n                    [nome] => jose\n                )\n\n        )\n\n    [_explicitType] => flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection\n)\n, referer: app:/OnSync.swf`

Comment: Your values are pretty deep in your object. Try something like 'error_log( print_r( $Object_param[ '_externalizedData' ], true))' or maybe just 'error_log( print_r( $object_param[ 0 ], true ))'. You'll have to experiment with these values to find the route to the array containing your data.

Comment: Is it the right way to put the data into object ? Do you see another better way ?
I got the error in both tries.
`[Mon Nov 26 18:16:56 2012] [error] [client 189.121.146.49] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /var/www/Amfphp/Services/Login.php on line 111, referer: app:/OnSync.swf`

Comment: `stdClass Object
(
    [_externalizedData] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [tipo_usuario] => 0
                   [username] => maria@maria.com.br
                   [nome] => maria
                )
        )
[_explicitType] => flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection
)`

Comment: I understood that I have access the property _externalizedData and the Array was there. Do you know how access this property and access the array inside?

Comment: It will be something like $obj[ '_externalizedData' ][0]['username'] or loop through it.

Comment: Now the error was PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use string offset as an array.