# PHP access CollectionArray data

Tags: php, apache-flex, flash-builder

How can I access the array data (i.e. id, nome, etc) of this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [_externalizedData] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                   [id] => 5
                   [tipo_usuario] => 0
                   [username] => maria@maria.com.br
                   [nome] => maria
                )
        )
[_explicitType] => flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection
)
```

Comment: more code please. what equals that object?

Comment: I am working to pass to AMFPHP a list of users in a data grid with multirows enabled. It are the parameters passed for Flex application to AMFPHP.

Comment: See more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548488/flex-datagrid-select-multiple-rows-and-send-to-amfphp-backend

Comment: Ok, I'll ask another way. What did you put to print that object?

Comment: error_log( print_r( $Object_param, true ));

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it would be, if `$object` equals that

```
$object->_externalizedData[0]->id
```

as in

```
echo $object->_externalizedData[0]->id; // 5    
echo $object->_externalizedData[0]->username; // maria@maria.com.br
```

OK more info given, that object =  `$Object_param` and OP wants to fix a loop

```
foreach ($Object_param->_externalizedData as $Obj)
{ 
    // line breaks just for readability 
    $query="INSERT INTO grupo_usuario 
        (id_grupo,id_usuario) 
        VALUES 
        (1, '" . mysql_real_escape_string($Obj->id) . "')";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$mysql); 
    error_log( print_r( $query, true )); 
}
```

But you're going to set id_grupo to 1 for each row. Hopefully you know how to sort the SQL out now you see how to get one variable.

Comment: Nice ! But it is not working yet.

`foreach($Object_param as $Obj){
                        $query="insert into grupo_usuario (id_grupo,id_usuario) values ('1','".$Obj->_externalizedData[0]->id."')";
                        $result = mysql_query($query,$mysql);
error_log( print_r( $query, true ));
                }`

Comment: I have more users passed as parameter and looks like this inside _externalizedData.

                `[1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                       [id] => 4
                       [tipo_usuario] => 0
                       [username] => john@john.com.br
                       [nome] => john
                    )`

Comment: :( Result: `[Mon Nov 26 23:18:00 2012] [error] [client 189.121.146.49] insert into grupo_usuario (id_grupo,id_usuario) values ('1',''), referer: app:/OnSync.swf`

Comment: would have been faster if you gave more info in your question but glad it works.

Comment: ...as in click accept this answer or whatever it says on this!

Answer (score 0):

You would access it like this:

```
$outer_class->_externalizedData[0]->nome
```